# Neural Net Convergence for Batch SGD

Tags: neural-networks, classification, image-recognition, backpropagation, stochastic-gradient-descent

I've built a dynamically sized neural network framework with for multi class classification—just to strengthen my understanding of the deep networks. I'm training and predicting my network to classify the MNIST digits—from what I've seen online shouldn't bee too hard a task. But even after training for an hour or two the highest accuracy it reaches on a validation set is ~50%.

I'm using sigmoid activations with a softmax in the final layer and using batched-GD with backprop to calculate gradients and step towards the min. I've checked the math for the backprop a few times and it seems right to me, but it's still take quite a long to time to train for quite a low accuracy. If anyone had any advice on how I could speedup training or point out any errors in my code, would be greatly appreciated.

I've included snippets of my code below:

Main code:

```
data = pd.read_csv('data/mnist.csv')

network = NeuralNetwork(2, [20, 10], 784)

train_data, test_data = train_test_split(data, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

network.stochasticGD(train_data, batch_size=1, max_iter=10000)

test = test_data.to_numpy()[:, :300]
print("Accuracy:", 100 * network.getAccuracy(test_data.to_numpy()))
```

Backprop function:

```
    def cross_entropy_grad(self, ypred, y):
        return ypred - y # 10 x b
    
    def backProp(self, ypred, y_one_hot):
        
        error = self.cross_entropy_grad(ypred, y_one_hot) # 10 x b
        
        for i, l in enumerate(self.layers[::-1]):
            if i != 0:
                error = error * l.deriv(l.z)
            error = l.backProp(error, self.alpha)
```

Layer.backprop Method:

```
    def backProp(self, dz, alpha): # nodes x batch
 
        dW = np.dot(dz, self.lastx.transpose()) / self.size        
        db = np.sum(dz, 1).reshape(self.size, 1) / self.size
        
        dx = np.dot(self.weights.transpose(), dz) #input x batch
        
        self.weights = self.weights - alpha * dW
        self.b = self.b - alpha * db
        
        return dx
```

Layer.forward Prop Method:

```
    def forwardProp(self, x):
        
        self.lastx = x
        
        self.one_vector = np.ones(shape=(1, len(x[0]))) # 1 x input size
        
        # nodes x batchSize
        self.z = np.dot(self.weights, x) + self.b.dot(self.one_vector)
        
        if np.any(np.isnan(self.z)) or np.any(np.isinf(self.z)):
            print(self.z)
            raise ValueError("Z computation")
        
        self.a = self.activ(self.z)
```

Batch GD Method:

```
  def stochasticGD(self, train_data, max_iter = 100, batch_size = 3):
        
        train_arr = train_data.to_numpy()
        
        
        for epoch in range(max_iter):
            
            # if epoch % self.updateRate == 0:
            #     self.updateVarRate(epoch)
                
            batch_indx = []
            
            for i in range(batch_size):
                batch_indx.append(random.randint(0, len(train_data) - 1))
                
            x_train = []
            y_train = []
            
            for i in batch_indx:
                datum = train_arr[i]
                y_val = datum[0]
                datum = np.delete(datum, 0)
                
                                
                y_one_hot = np.zeros(10)
                y_one_hot[y_val] = 1
                
                y_train.append(y_one_hot)
                x_train.append(datum)
                
            x_train = np.array(x_train) # 784 x b
            y_train = np.array(y_train) # b x 10
            
            y_train = y_train.transpose() # 10 x b

                                    
            output = self.forwardProp(x_train)
            self.backProp(output, y_train)
            

                
            
            if epoch % 1 == 0:
                print('Epoch:', epoch)
                print("   Accuracy:", 100 * self.getAccuracy(train_arr))
                print("   Rate:", self.varRate)
            #print(np.sum(output, axis=0))
```